# Getting Redux Framework Warning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, redux-framework

I am working on a word-press project which is using Redux Framework. I am getting error.

> Redux Framework Warning select2-css CDN unavailable. Some controls may
>   not render properly. Please wait a few minutes, then try refreshing
>   the page. Unable to load some remotely hosted scripts..

Please let me know what is the problem and how to solve it..?? I am not able to edit my theme.

Thanks

Comment: What code is returning this error? You should post the code that's being used to help diagnose the cause.

Comment: I am getting this error on my theme option page.. My theme option panel is using this framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's not our CDN, don't know. I can only assume you're using the latest version of Redux from this repo. You didn't say.3.5.7.9 - but nothing regarding the CDN has changed. If wp_remote_get fails, that message appears. Again, it's not our CDN. I've been working all day on a Redux related project, and I've not seen that message. If you're working local, you might check the connection, or if worse comes to worst, install the https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-vendor-support on your local.Without going onto the server and debugging? Nope. None. That's a premium support service now. As I said, if wp_remote_get fails, that's the message. So why would wp_remote_get fail on that server? Look at your php error logs and see if it's a php config issue (if any), Find out what the return value of wp_remote_get is (class.redux_cdn.php, line 61). The answer is probably in the wp_error array.

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev of Redux here. It means your instance doesn't have access to the web. The easily solution is to install the Redux Vendor Support plugin (found here): https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-vendor-support

This will allow your site to function offline.